# Can't start the docker image of the restcomm load balancer

Tags: restcomm

While trying to start the docker image found [here](https://github.com/RestComm/load-balancer-docker) for restcomm's load balancer I get the following error.

```
2017-01-09 13:40:41,359 ERROR main org.mobicents.tools.sip.balancer.BalancerRunner.start(BalancerRunner.java:280) - An unexpected error occurred while starting the load balancer
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't create sip objects and lps due to[Index: 0, Size: 0]
        at org.mobicents.tools.sip.balancer.SIPBalancerForwarder.start(SIPBalancerForwarder.java:792)
        at org.mobicents.tools.sip.balancer.BalancerRunner.start(BalancerRunner.java:255)
        at org.mobicents.tools.sip.balancer.BalancerRunner.start(BalancerRunner.java:346)
        at org.mobicents.tools.sip.balancer.BalancerRunner.main(BalancerRunner.java:150)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:492)
        at org.mobicents.tools.sip.balancer.SIPBalancerForwarder.start(SIPBalancerForwarder.java:357)
        ... 3 more
```

I ran the following Docker run command

```
docker run --name=lb -e LOG_LEVEL=all restcomm/load-balancer:latest
```

I tried looking up the code lines in the stack trace from the [Load Balancer GitHub Repo](https://github.com/RestComm/load-balancer) but it appears the docker image does not contain the exact same code so the line numbers referenced don't match up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. We have updated the image for the docker container. Please do the following.

```
docker rm  lb
```

this will remove the previous container

next do a pull to get the new image

```
docker pull restcomm/load-balancer:latest
```

once the pull is completed try running the load balancer again as follows:

```
docker run --name=lb  restcomm/load-balancer:latest
```

regards

Charles